# How to interact with Termux from a Unity app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I am looking to run a Termux session in the background and display a UI to interact with it in my Unity Android application. I have done some digging and came across the following Wiki doc on Termux:

[RUN_COMMAND Intent](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/wiki/RUN_COMMAND-Intent)

I have successfully completed the setup process described on the page, but am now faced with the following example snippet:

```java
intent.setClassName("com.termux", "com.termux.app.RunCommandService");
intent.setAction("com.termux.RUN_COMMAND");
intent.putExtra("com.termux.RUN_COMMAND_PATH", "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/top");
intent.putExtra("com.termux.RUN_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS", new String[]{"-n", "5"});
intent.putExtra("com.termux.RUN_COMMAND_WORKDIR", "/data/data/com.termux/files/home");
intent.putExtra("com.termux.RUN_COMMAND_BACKGROUND", false);
intent.putExtra("com.termux.RUN_COMMAND_SESSION_ACTION", "0");
startService(intent);
```

How would you approach converting something like this into a Unity C# script?

**For example, if I wanted to start a Termux session and simply run `ls` in the current directory, how would you approach this?**

Comment: Sounds a lot of work just to get a list of files which you can almost certainly get without

Comment: I'm trying to do quite a lot more than just access files. I would like to be able to run a Node server locally in the background, along with manage source control through Git, really whatever the user wants to use it for.